# Routing through a VPN tunnel with Linux machines

Tags: linux, routing, vpn-client

I have two Linux machines connected with a VPN tunnel:

```
VPN Client <-------> VPN Server
10.74.1.10/24         10.74.1.1/24
```

Each one has NICs to reach their own networks:

```
---------> VPN Client <-------------------> VPN Server <------
10.37.0.205/24   10.74.1.10/24      10.74.1.1/24    10.74.0.1/24
```

And, of course, I have different Linux computers (Linux A, Linux B, etc.) on each network:

```
Linux A  <----> VPN Client <-----> VPN Server <----> Linux B
```

From `VPN Client`, I can ping to `VPN Server` and computers like `Linux B`.

Although, from `Linux A`, I can ping to both `VPN Client` machine's interfaces (`10.32.0.205` and `10.74.1.10`), it turns out **I can't ping to `VPN Server` with address `10.74.1.1` or to any computer on the network B**.

I tried to add a new route on `Linux A`, but I get this:

```
$ sudo ip route add 10.74.1.1 via 10.74.1.10 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable

$ sudo ip route add 10.74.1.1 via 10.37.0.205 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

How can I make this works? Maybe configuring something on `VPN Client`?

**EDIT:**

The route table on `VPN Client` is this:

```
default via 10.37.0.1 dev eth0 
10.37.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.37.0.205 
10.74.0.0/16 via 10.74.1.9 dev tun0 
10.74.1.0/24 via 10.74.1.9 dev tun0 
10.74.1.9 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.74.1.10 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.74.1.9 dev tun0
```

The route table on `Linux A`:

```
default via 10.37.1.1 dev eth0 
10.37.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.37.1.217
```

Also, I activated IP forwarding on `VPN Client`

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

**EDIT 2:**

Filtering packet on `VPN Client`:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of VPN are you using?

Sounds like your `VPN Client` should NAT traffic from `Linux A` to your `VPN Server` & `Linux B`.
And/or: your `Linux B` does not have a route back to your `VPN Client`.

Comment: I'm using OpenVPN... So, do I need to configure NAT on Client VPN? I didn't do something like that yet.

Comment: You were right. The problem was the NAT configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your un-natted packets were passing through your VPN tunnel, then your OpenVPN server logs did probably tell about discarding traffic from unknown IPs. Nice to see you figured it out.

Comment: It is possible and cleaner to set this up without NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling to find a simple solution to a problem similar to this and found that sshuttle is the simplest for at least a temporary solution, as it were for me.

One linux machine have access to a VPN and with sshuttle running on another machine I got access to that VPN.

Furthermore the routing could be easily filtered using a cidr block as the last parameter. This improved the usability in the second machine since not every call goes to the VPN-enabled machine.

```
sshuttle --dns -r user@192.168.86.100 10.208.0.0/16
```

Link: https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle

Installation only necessary on the client. SSH access to the VPN-enabled machine is all that is required on that end.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a route then the next hop must be link-local. `Linux A` can reach only the addresses 10.37.1.0/24 directly. But

```
ip route add 10.74.1.1 via 10.74.1.10 dev eth0
```

says: Send a packet to 10.74.1.1 to the link-local host 10.74.1.10. As 10.74.1.10 is not link-local (or: not configured as such) you get the error message `Network is unreachable`.

The next hop must be the local address of `VPN Client`:

```
ip route add 10.74.1.1 via 10.37.0.205 dev eth0
```